# i'm looking for a specific button in linear layout with foreach

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
 for(Button b : **myLayout**){

/*error: foreach not applicable to type Android.widget.LinearLayout */


}
```

Comment: Why should you use a foreach to get a specific button?

Comment: Because i think is the easiest way

Comment: Do you know the id?

Comment: no, that's why I use these instructions to retrieve the Id

Comment: But what is the condition to check to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
    ViewGroup root = findViewById(R.id.root);
    for (int i=0; i<root.getChildCount(); i++){
        View child = root.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof Button){
            //...do something
        }
    }
```